# Android Studio: Resources.NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-resources

My code ran fine on the emulator, however, as soon as I tried running my code on a device (in this case a Nexus 5) I started to get A LOT of Resources.NotFoundExceptions. The majority of the exceptions occur in relation to drawable or color files. For example:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/blob_ocean.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060066
```

Logcat then states that the error is caused by:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/blob_ocean.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060066
```

then it states that the previous error is caused by:

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/radial_pink.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f04004e
```

The two examples occur in a fragment on the line with the AnimatedVectorDrawable.

```
public class BlobFragment extends Fragment {
private AnimatedVectorDrawable blob;
private ImageView blobView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blob_fragment, container, false);
    blobView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.blob_o);
    blob = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.blob_ocean, null);
    blobView.setImageDrawable(blob);
    blob.start();
    return v;
}
```

}

The layout for the fragment looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OceanThemeActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blob_o"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blob_ocean"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.271"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have looked online but have not been able to find something that works. Having a hard time identifying the issue as everything is working fine in an emulator.

Comment: What is os version of your device?

Comment: Are your resources in density-specific buckets? xhdpi, ldpi, etc? And if so, are there resources for a density bucket corresponding to that particular phone's density?

Comment: check your drawable folder if the file is correct

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It was related to backward compatibility; I was using AnimatedVectorDrawable which is only working for API 24 or higher and my device was lower. Changing the objects to AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat fixed it. Also, some of the drawable recourses were too big, making them smaller worked perfectly fine.